# create a filter from cgi, env variables not being passed

Tags: php, filter, environment-variables, cgi

I've got a compiled C program which is a cgi, which works fine if I call it directly from php web page with appropriate GET or POST requests.
I'm trying to have a php program call the cgi, capture the data and modify it before echoing it back to the user.

I've tried:

```
<?php
    foreach($_REQUEST as $i => $j)
        apache_setenv($i,$j);
    $out = shell_exec("cgi-bin/Mycgi.cgi");
    // will modify out here
    echo $out;
?>
```

but Mycgi.cgi never sees the environment variables.  Am I totally misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?
where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the environment variables explicitly using [`putenv`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php), before calling `shell_exec` in your script.

```
putenv("VARIABLE=value");
```

Comment: Yes I tried that as well. (substitute putenv("$i=$j") with  apache_setenv($i,$j) same result.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, which works very well is:
in php build up a string with the following info (QUERY_STRING is just and example)

```
$qs = 
    'env REQUEST_METHOD=GET QUERY_STRING="Birthday=15&BirthMonth=3&BirthYear=1988" ../../cgi-bin/mycgi.cgi';
$output = '';
exec($qs,$output);
```

And that's all there is to it.